# Why HSQL not support count function in a spring batch project

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-batch, hsqldb

> I am new to SpringBatch And HSQL, I simple create an application. I
> want to select all the rows from the table ,So I write custom query By
> using EntityManager but when I Use COUNT(*),and pass Star symbol
> inside the count function it show me an error Like this

```
<expression>, ALL, DISTINCT or identifier expected, got '*'
```

> How to I use * symbol inside the Count function in Hsql
>
> Here is the my query details
> JobCompleteNotificationListner.kt

```
package com.nilmani.privatecricketleague.data

import com.nilmani.privatecricketleague.model.Team
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution
import org.springframework.batch.core.listener.JobExecutionListenerSupport
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.EntityManager
import javax.persistence.Transient
import kotlin.collections.HashMap

class JobCompleteNotificationListner : JobExecutionListenerSupport {
    val log:Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompleteNotificationListner::class.java)
    val em:EntityManager

    constructor(em:EntityManager){this.em= em}

    @Transient
    override fun afterJob(jobExcution:JobExecution){
        if (jobExcution.status == BatchStatus.COMPLETED){
            log.info("Job finished Time to verify the result")

            val teamData:Map<String,Team> = HashMap()
            em.createQuery("SELECT m.team1 , COUNT(*) FROM match m GROUP BY m.team1",Objects::class.java)
        }
    }

}
```

> I get error at this below line

```
em.createQuery("SELECT m.team1 , COUNT(*) FROM match m GROUP BY m.team1",Objects::class.java)
```

Comment: Have you tried `COUNT(ALL)` as the message suggests?

Comment: I already do this way but Nothing happen,Showing same issue,So I Move all and use *

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: <expression>, ALL, DISTINCT or identifier expected, got '*' this type of error message

Comment: The error message is not from HSQLDB. It probably means you need `COUNT(colName)` where colName is the name of a column of the `match` table other than `m.teams1`

Comment: This is not related to Spring Batch. You need to make sure your query works as expected before using it in a Spring Batch job.